# How can I resolve the connection error to the project in visual studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

Getting the below error while trying to connect the proj in Visual Studio 2019 version:

> An attempt to communicate with Azure DevOps failed because a token could not be retrieved. Please re-enter your credentials.

Tried deleting the cache and other steps specified in various other blogs but nothing seems to work.

Any insights would be really helpful!

Comment: Have you tried to "Sign out" the Visual Studio and restart of Visual Studio and signing back in?

Comment: Yes… I have tried signing out and signing in back after restarting the VS. The strange thing here is.. VS 2015 took me through but the projects are not getting loaded. VS 2019 doesn’t take me through the sign in itself… not sure why